# how to get context and env variables in asyncData nuxtjs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm creating a blog in my nuxt-app that pulls data from contentful ive been following this [tutorial](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/javascript/tutorials/integrate-contentful-with-vue-and-nuxt/), now I can get that all right, but I cant seem to get both context and the environment variables I set up to return from the `asyncData` argument

I have created a json file like so..

**.contentful.json**

```
{
  "CTF_BLOG_POST_ITEM": "...",
  "CTF_BLOG_POST": "...",
  "CTF_SPACE_ID": "...",
  "CTF_CDA_ACCESS_TOKEN":"..."
}
```

and then in my **nuxt.config.js**

```
env: {
   CTF_SPACE_ID: config.CTF_SPACE_ID,
   CTF_CDA_ACCESS_TOKEN: config.CTF_CDA_ACCESS_TOKEN,
   CTF_BLOG_POST_ITEM: config.CTF_BLOG_POST_ITEM,
   CTF_BLOG_POST: config.CTF_BLOG_POST
}
```

now basically in my component I've been trying to do this

```
asyncData(context, {env}) {
    return Promise.all([
        client.getEntries({
            'content_type': env.CTF_BLOG_POST_ITEM,
            order: '-sys.createdAt'
        })
    ]).then(([posts]) => {
        console.log(context);
        return {
            posts: posts.items
        }
    })
},
```

but when I run this I get `cannot read property CTF_BLOG_POST_ITEM of undefined`, if I take context out of the arguments this works, and vice versa if I take the `{env}` I get the context.

How can I get both??

Thanks

Comment: this node package will surely help
https://www.npmjs.com/package/nuxt-env

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary (1st) argument of [asyncData()](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data) is the [context object](https://nuxtjs.org/api/context). `env` is a property of the context object. You could access it as `context.env` without the use of [object restructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring). Your  example could be rewritten in the following way without the use of object restructuring assignment:

```
asyncData(context) {
    return Promise.all([
        client.getEntries({
            'content_type': context.env.CTF_BLOG_POST_ITEM,
            order: '-sys.createdAt'
        })
    ]).then(([posts]) => {
        console.log(context);
        console.log(context.env);
        return {
            posts: posts.items
        }
    })
},
```

The signature `asyncData(context, {env}) {` is incorrect because you are adding a second argument, `{env}`, which does not reference the aforementioned context object in any way. If you only need `env` from `context`, you can use [object restructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) to extract this property in the following way (as you mentioned works when you remove the 1st argument:

```
 asyncData({env}) {
    return Promise.all([
        client.getEntries({
            'content_type': context.env.CTF_BLOG_POST_ITEM,
            order: '-sys.createdAt'
        })
    ]).then(([posts]) => {
        console.log(context);
        console.log(context.env);
        return {
            posts: posts.items
        }
    })
},
```

If you need additional context object properties, using object destructuring assignment. Tt would look like:

```
asyncData({env, params, req, res}) {
```

Otherwise, you can just access properties such as `context.env`, `context.params`, etc by simply passing `context` as the first/primary argument with restructuring.

Hopefully that helps!